# Is there anyway to have the search bar on the same paragraph?

Tags: php, css

Is there anyway to have the search bar on the same paragraph? It keeps dropping down.... :/

```
<li><a href="tree.php">Account</a></li>
<input type="text" class="uiinput" id="searchinput"  />
<div style="float:right;"/><li><a href='<?php echo $base_url; ?>logout.php' style='color:#fff'>Log Out </a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Please help me!

Comment: The HTML you have posted is not valid.  You have an `<input> , <div>` which are not children of `<li>` nested inside a `<ul>`

Comment: furthermore, `<li>` tags put the content to a new line; thats what they are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could begin by putting the inputs and divs in their own `li`s to fix Michael Berkowski's good observation (namely, that your `HTML` is invalid)

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="tree.php">Account</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" class="uiinput" id="searchinput" />
      <div style="float:right;"/><a href='<?php echo $base_url; ?>logout.php' style='color:#fff'>Log Out </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

then you could apply `float:left;` to the `li`s.

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

This is untested, but something like this will start you off in the right direction. Note that it disregards other problems with the code, like how it seems that you're using a `list` inappropriately.